# Creating child instances at the same time as their parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a polling system:

```
# models
class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :poll
end

# routes
resources :polls do
  resources :answers
end
```

`Poll` having one string attribute, `question`, and `Answer` having one string attribute, `answer`, and one integer, `votes`.

I'd like to have it so when a user creates a `Poll`, a form for a nested `Answer` instance is displayed. Then have a button with an AJAX call for another form (allowing up to say 10) so multiple answers can be added.

I know how to do the AJAX part, but I don't know how to add child instances to a parent that doesn't exist yet.

The only way I can think of is to use a `text_field_tag` to pass it through params, then manually create it in the `PollsController` `create` method. Sort of like this:

```
def create
  @poll = @poll.create(poll_params)

  if @poll.save
    if params[:poll_answer1].present?
      @poll.answers.create!(answer: params[:poll_answer1])
    end

    if params[:poll_answer2].present?
      @poll.answers.create!(answer: params[:poll_answer2])
    end

    flash[:notice] = "Poll created."
    redirect_to @poll
  else
    flash[:error] = "Poll could not be created."
    render :new
  end
end
```

But it seems like there should be a better way. I'm not opposed to scrapping the entire setup, and maybe placing the questions in an array attribute on `Poll` instead. But then there's the issue of counting votes.

Comment: Take a look at Rails `accepts_nested_attributes_for` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) - specifically the one-to-many portion of that link. It will allow you to create a `Poll` and as many `Answer`s as you want simultaneously.

Comment: The previous comment is the way to go. In doing so, check out https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon to make your life easier.

Comment: @james00794 That looks perfect, thank you!